# JMock class mocks in Spring Context

Tags: java, spring, autowired, jmock

I'd like to inject JMock mock beans from Spring XML Configuration. 
I have the following test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "/application-context-test.xml")
public class CorporateInfoServiceImplTest
{
    @Autowired
    private Mockery mockery;

    @Autowired
    private CorporateInfoServiceImpl corporateInfoService;

    @Test
    public void createCorporateInfo() {...}
}
```

And such XML configuration:

```
<bean id="mockery" class="org.jmock.Mockery">
  <property name="imposteriser">
    <util:constant static-field="org.jmock.lib.legacy.ClassImposteriser.INSTANCE"/>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="createCorporateInfoOperation" class="com.acme.corp.ws.operation.CreateCorporateInfoOperation" factory-bean="mockery" factory-method="mock">
  <constructor-arg value="com.acme.corp.ws.operation.CreateCorporateInfoOperation" type="java.lang.Class" />
</bean>

<bean id="corporateInfoService" class="com.acme.corp.ws.CorporateInfoServiceImpl">
  <property name="createCorporateInfoOperation" ref="createCorporateInfoOperation" />
</bean>
```

CorporateInfoServiceImpl and CreateCorporateInfoOperation are kind of:

```
public class CorporateInfoServiceImpl implements CorporateServiceInterface
{
    @Autowired
    CreateCorporateInfoOperation createCorporateInfoOperation;
    ...
}

@Component
public class CreateCorporateInfoOperation
{

    @Autowired
    CorporateInfoDao corporateInfoDao;
    ...
}
```

When trying to autowire the CorporateInfoServiceImpl I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.acme.corp.dao.CorporateInfoDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

The problem is that CreateCorporateInfoOperation tries to autowire dao even when created form factory-method. How can I disable such autowiring?

Other variants of injecting mock beans in JMock are appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are creating a mock of the class not the interface. Hence the mock is still a `CreateCorporateInfoOperation` which has all the annotations. Instead create a mock for `ICreateCorporateInfoOperation`. Which you should also use in your `CorporateInfoServiceImpl` instead of the concrete class (yu should be programming to interfaces in the first place).

Comment: @M. Deinum, Thanks. I've already thought about such solution. But I have  a lot of operations and creating an interface for each would be a great overhead

Comment: Your question is about this specific situation. You have already an interface and you aren't programming to interfaces. You are creating an instance of the class which will always have the annotations and those will always be processed. There is no mocking library that is going you to help you with that. Instead of using Spring (which is what you want imho) ditch the xml and just construct the mock and object manually. If it is a unit (and not an integration/system) test that should the primary way for testing.

Comment: @M. Deinum, my bad. Already removed ICreateCorporateInfoOperation.